# get records of past two months excluding today's record list

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join, left-join

I have two queries:

Following query return me the guards details who are working today:

**One:**

```
 SELECT
    `guards`.`surname`
    , `contracted_guard`.`con_id`
    , `guards`.`street`
    , `shifts`.`advised_sign_in`
FROM
    `guards`
LEFT JOIN `contracted_guard` ON `contracted_guard`.`guard_id` = `guards`.`gid`
LEFT JOIN `shifts` ON `shifts`.`guard_id` = `guards`.`gid`
WHERE advised_sign_in >=CURDATE()
AND advised_sign_in < CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY `guards`.`gid`
ORDER BY `guards`.`given_names` ASC
LIMIT 400
```

Now, the following second query returns me the guards details who are not working today but have signed in at least for once in past two months (This is because to get the list of active guards as system contains a huge guard list).

**Query Two:**

```
SELECT
    `guards`.`surname`
    , `contracted_guard`.`con_id`
    , `guards`.`street`
    , `shifts`.`advised_sign_in`
FROM
    `guards`
    LEFT JOIN `contracted_guard` 
        ON (`contracted_guard`.`guard_id` = `guards`.`gid`)
    LEFT JOIN `shifts` 
        ON (`shifts`.`guard_id` = `guards`.`gid`)
WHERE (`shifts`. advised_sign_in !=CURDATE() AND advised_sign_in >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
GROUP BY `guards`.`gid`
ORDER BY `guards`.`given_names` ASC;
```

The both queries work fine. But the problem is second query return the result of those guards also who are working today as well but with old date (THis is because they also have signed in in past two months). Although i want the list of guards excluding those guards who are working today but have worked in past two months.

Any hints will be highly appreciated .

Comment: Try `SELECT ... , max(\`shifts\`.\`advised_sign_in\`) as \`last_sign_in\` FROM ...` to get the most recent sign-in time for each `guard` and replace the corresponding identifiers in your `WHERE clause`. `GROUP BY` queries are of not much use without using an "accumulation function" (`sum()`, `count()`, `max()`, `min` ...).

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the condition on the current date from the `where` to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT `guards`.`surname`, `contracted_guard`.`con_id`, `guards`.`street`, `shifts`.`advised_sign_in`
FROM `guards`
     LEFT JOIN `contracted_guard` 
        ON (`contracted_guard`.`guard_id` = `guards`.`gid`)
     LEFT JOIN `shifts` 
        ON (`shifts`.`guard_id` = `guards`.`gid`)
WHERE advised_sign_in >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
GROUP BY `guards`.`gid`
HAVING sum(`shifts`. advised_sign_in = CURDATE() ) = 0
ORDER BY `guards`.`given_names` ASC;
```

Comment: Still no difference in result.

Comment: @RK. . . . This should not return any guard who has signed in today.  Is it possible that `advised_sign_in` has a time component on it?  If so, you want `having sum(date(`shifts`. advised_sign_in) = CURDATE() ) = 0`.